# for flutter desktop app how to create a text field which accepts only number with TextEditingController not working

Tags: flutter

Below is my flutter code. I am trying to create desktop app and I need a text field that only accepts only numbers. But when I run below code as a desktop app it is allowing both alphabets and numbers. any suggestion where I am going wrong

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Number Sum',
      home: const NumberSumScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class NumberSumScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NumberSumScreen({super.key});
  @override
  State<NumberSumScreen> createState() => _NumberSumScreenState();
}

class _NumberSumScreenState extends State<NumberSumScreen> {
  TextEditingController num1Controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num2Controller = TextEditingController();
  int totalSum = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Number Sum')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: num1Controller,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              maxLength: 10,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter Number 1 (10 digits)'),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: num2Controller,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              maxLength: 10,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Enter Number 2 (10 digits)'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                calculateSum();
              },
              child: const Text('Calculate Sum'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            Text(
              'Total Sum: $totalSum',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void calculateSum() {
    int num1 = int.tryParse(num1Controller.text) ?? 0;
    int num2 = int.tryParse(num2Controller.text) ?? 0;
    setState(() {
      totalSum = num1 + num2;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use input formatters that accept digits only.

Example:

```html
TextField(
    controller: num2Controller,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    maxLength: 10,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
         labelText: 'Enter Number 2 (10 digits)'),
    inputFormatters: [
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
      ],
),
```